# Why won't something print with desired precision in a while loop?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I have a problem: when I ask something to print with precision P, that is, Print[N[something, P]], it does not print with precision P, just with the usual output precision.

In particular, I have a triple nested while-loop, something of the form

> While[p<...,
>
> While[k<... ,
>
> While[n<***+1,
>
> *process in which Y[n] is defined*
>
> n++ ]
>
> Print[N[Y[***],100]];
>
> k++ ]
>
> p++ ]

Then the output prints Y[***] each time to the default printed precision, not 100. Other than this, my code works as expected.

Does anyone have an idea what I can do to fix this?

---

(My code is very long and I am doing an assignment where only small hints about parts of the code is allowed, so I don't think I should post my full code here. I hope I've provided enough and not too much detail.)

Comment: Hard to say why without a MWE. It could be a bug, but hard to know. I tried this on 10.3.1 and it works: `Print[N[Pi, 100]]`. Can't you make a small example to show the problem? I just also add there might not be enough precision in the number itself.

Comment: OTOH, `Print[N[3.14, 100]]` will not print 100 digits (as expected).  `Y[***]` must have at least a precision of 100 (or be exact) to get 100 digits of precision.

Comment: good example @MichaelE2, but this prints 100 digits: "Print[N[3.14`100, 100]]"   :)

Comment: @Nasser Also printing `SetPrecision[3.14, 100]` would print 100 digits, as would `SetPrecision[Y[***], 100]`, though all beyond the precision of the number should be treated as garbage.  (I thought our first comments covered the main points pretty well.)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this question has little to do with `Print`. Consider

```
N[N[Pi, 6], 100]
```

> `3.14159`

`N` can reduce the precision of its first argument, but it can't increase it. It seems likely to me that `Y[***]`, whatever it actually is, simply doesn't represent anything that can evaluated to 100 digits of precision.